# Something is overriding my constraints

Tags: c#, ios, nslayoutconstraint

I have a view which I load from a nib, add to a superview, and then add some constraints. However the bounds turn out wrong, and when I look at the view with "Debug View Hierarchy", it shows some other constraints being active instead of mine. I can't figure out where they came from and why they're overriding the ones I set.

Xcode shows this:

[image]

They grayed-out constraints are my own, either from the nib or added at runtime. The top four are the mystery ones.

The code is in C# but it's pretty straightforward:

```
var notificationView = UINib.FromName("NotificationView", null)
                            .Instantiate(null, null).OfType<NotificationView>().FirstOrDefault();
var constraints = new[]
{
    notificationView.WidthAnchor.ConstraintEqualTo(window.WidthAnchor, 0.5f, 0),
    notificationView.CenterXAnchor.ConstraintEqualTo(window.CenterXAnchor),
    notificationView.HeightAnchor.ConstraintEqualTo(OverlayHeight),
    notificationView.TopAnchor.ConstraintEqualTo(window.TopAnchor, -OverlayHeight),
};

window.AddSubview(notificationView);
NSLayoutConstraint.ActivateConstraints(constraints);
```

The view that I'm adding it to is the main window; I don't know if that matters or not.

(I'm trying to start with a negative top because it's supposed to animate in from off-screen, but that's not working because of this issue)

Where are the extra constraints coming from, and how do I get rid of/override them?

Comment: You can enable Malloc Stack Logging for 'All Allocation and Free History' in your scheme options (Diagnostics tab). When you then select a constraint in the view debugger (or any other element), the inspector will show you the creation backtrace for it. Remember to turn this back off as it can affect the target's performance.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

When adding constraints manually to a view, you usually want to remove the constraints created by the autoresizing mask.

To do so, simply add:

```
notificationView.TranslatesAutoresizingMaskIntoConstraints = false;
```

After

```
window.AddSubview(notificationView);
```

Comment: Doing that right after loading works too. I think I've been bitten by this before... the thing is the docs say you don't have to do that for views loaded from a nib. I've just got to remember that they're wrong.